# Javascript blobtrigger sample function crashes with StorageException

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

A brand new javascript FunctionApp with a blobtriggered function crashes with error 500 :

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Queues\Listeners\QueueListener.cs:line 155
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\TaskSeriesTimer.cs:line 147
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnUnhandledExceptionAsync>b__0() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\WebJobsExceptionHandler.cs:line 54
>      at System.Threading.Thread.ThreadMain_ThreadStart()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Steps : I created a new FunctionApp with :

- in javascript
- on a windows serviceplan
- brand new storage/resource group

Next, I navigated to the FunctionApp and created a new function :

- from portal
- with "Azure Blob Storage trigger" template (I installed the storage extension)
- default storage path, var names, etc

Next, I created the container "samples-workitems" on the storage and put a file in it to trigger the function and have the error message from the function logs.

I also tried to "test" the function from the right panel in the portal with the value samples-workitems/{the file I copied} and I got a 500 error and the previous message.

Something weird I noticed by going back to the function app in web portal :

[image]
Azure storage extension seems properly installed but if I try to add a new blob triggered function, it asks me again to install the storage extension... So I guess it never succeed to install the extension and is not able to do it.

**EDIT:** Turns out Azure now aknowledges that the extension is installed but I still have the StorageException

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an extension is successfully installed or not from [Kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/). Open DebugConsole --> Go to D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.dll. If the storage dll is not there, extension installation did not succeed.

Comment: Yes, the dll is in the bin folder. But adding a new blob trigger funciton from the portal tells me it isn't installed : "This template requires the following extensions.
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage"

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to reinstall the extensions you want . You could refer to this wiki: [Update your app from portal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#update-your-app-from-portal).

Edit the `extensions.csproj` file, make the required additions and updates of `PackageReference` items in the `ItemGroup`, then select Save. About the supported package versions can be found in the [What NuGet packages do i need?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#what-nuget-packages-do-i-need).

Then in the `wwwroot` folder run the below command to build the referenced assemblies.

```
dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget
```

Comment: Azure now aknowledges that the extension is installed but I still have the StorageException